# Internet API to get atomic time

Tags: time

I am writing a locally-run app that needs to check the internet with a web call to verify the actual time - it doesn't trust the clock on the user's computer.

I'm searching all over and can't find some publicly available API that can just return this.

What I am doing is super low volume, so I am looking for something that doesn't require API keys - it can just be requested, or, if need be, scraped.

Anyone know of anything like this?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow […]."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the following url.
http://www.timeapi.org/

To get current UTC time you can do something like this.
http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now